# What is the current mechanism to construct a query string with SuperAgent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpclient

I am trying to use [SuperAgent .data() to construct a query string per the docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/docs/index.md). However .data() no longer seems to exist.

```
superagent
    .get(URL)
    .data({ 'screen_name': USER, 'count': '1' })
    .end(function(response){        
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('yay got ' + JSON.stringify(response.body));
        } else {
            console.log('Oh no! error ' + response.text);
        }
});
```

Results in:

```
Object #<Request> has no method 'data'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer didn't work for me in the latest version of SuperAgent (0.18.0). I had to instead use the `query` function (http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#query-strings).

```
request.get("/search").query({ search: 'query' }).end(callback);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace `.data` with `.send`

Based on the comments in the source:

```
  /**
   * Send `data`, defaulting the `.type()` to "json" when
   * an object is given.
   *
   * Examples:
   *
   *       // querystring
   *       request.get('/search')
   *         .send({ search: 'query' })
   *         .end(callback)
   *
   *       // multiple data "writes"
   *       request.get('/search')
   *         .send({ search: 'query' })
   *         .send({ range: '1..5' })
   *         .send({ order: 'desc' })
   *         .end(callback)
   *
   *       // manual json
   *       request.post('/user')
   *         .type('json')
   *         .send('{"name":"tj"})
   *         .end(callback)
   *       
   *       // auto json
   *       request.post('/user')
   *         .send({ name: 'tj' })
   *         .end(callback)
   *       
   *       // manual x-www-form-urlencoded
   *       request.post('/user')
   *         .type('form')
   *         .send('name=tj')
   *         .end(callback)
   *       
   *       // auto x-www-form-urlencoded
   *       request.post('/user')
   *         .type('form')
   *         .send({ name: 'tj' })
   *         .end(callback)
   *
   * @param {String|Object} data
   * @return {Request} for chaining
   * @api public
   */
```

Comment: Thanks Cheery! It seems the docs are a little behind the source - I did open them to check but obviously missed this.

Comment: This answer is outdated. You can't use `send` with `get`: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/606